# Subversion URL shortcuts

Tags: svn, keyboard-shortcuts

There is one shortcut I know of, ^ which means "the base URL of the current repository". I know there a bunch of other ones introduced with Subversion 1.6. What are they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- '../' : Parent directory's URL (only at start of URL)
- '^/'  : Repository root URL
- '/'   : Server URL
- '//'  : Relative to protocol of server URL (e.g. http://)

Comment: Since version 1.6 is rather old I removed the link.